# Tornado shell command to find current system date in vxworks 5.5

Tags: c, date, command, vxworks

I am using tornado 2.2 in Vxworks PPC board for running my C program. What is the Tornado shell command to get current sytem time. Google is not giving any answer for it, its only giving details about C system call to find system date.

This vxworks board is connected to a windows xp machine. I am able to see system time in windows. I hope vxworks board time is different from windows machine time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the vxwork board is rebooted, system time will get resetted to 1970. `time` command will returns the number of seconds ticked from 1970. To get and set the time in standard presentable format, we have to implement a [C program](http://csg.lbl.gov/pipermail/vxwexplo/2003-August/002745.html).